# Draw a "super-twisting" curve TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, draw, tikz-graphdrawing, curve-fitting

I am trying to draw the "twisted" curve in the pic:

[image]

I am not an expert in Tikz, and I have written the following latex code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}  %% Add decoration library
%\usetikzlibrary{knots}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
 \pagestyle{plain}

 \begin{document}




% SET ARROW STYLE WITH TIP IN THE MIDDLE OF THE LINE
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position -0.3 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}
        
        
\tikzset{line/.style={->,shorten <=0.4cm,shorten >=0.4cm}}

\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% 
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=5cm,>=latex']
        
        % DRAW AXIS
        \draw[->](-2,0)--(3,0);
        \draw[->](0,-2)--(0,4);
        \node at(3.2,0)(x){\large$x$};
        \node at(0.25,4)(xy){\large$\dot{x}$};
        
        % DRAW CURVES
        \draw[->-] (0,3) .. controls (-0.001,2)  and (1.9,-1) .. (0,-0.5);
        \draw[-] (0,-0.5) .. controls (-0.1,-0.08) and (-0.3,-0.2)  .. (-0.25,0);
        \draw[-] (-0.25,0) .. controls (-0.1,0.4) and (0,0)  .. (0.05,0);
        \draw[-] (0.05,0) .. controls (0.1,-0.2) and (0.05,-0.2)   .. (0,-0.03);
        
        \node at(0.2,0.2)(x){\large$0$};
        
        

    \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
    \end{document}
```

but what I get is something a little bit different from what I want:[image]

I could improve my code?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified slightly your code.  There were unneeded commands that I erased and I modified the points of the curve to fit the model.
[image]

**Notation remark.**  0 is a real number.  I think you need the letter *O* to denote the origin.

The code:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

% SET ARROW STYLE WITH TIP IN THE MIDDLE OF THE LINE
\tikzset{%
  ->-/.style={%
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position .65 with {\arrow[scale=1.2]{stealth}}
    },
    postaction={decorate}
  },
  >=stealth
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  % DRAW AXIS
  \draw[->] (-1, 0) -- (2, 0) node[above right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0, -1.5) -- (0, 4) node[left] {$\dot{x}$};

  % DRAW CURVE
  \draw[blue, thick, ->-] (0, 3)
  to[out=270, in=90] (1, 0)
  .. controls +(0, -.4) and (.8, -1.1) .. (.4, -1.1)
  .. controls +(-.2, 0) and (0, -.8) .. (0, -.5)
  .. controls +(0, .3) and (-.2, -.2) .. (-.2, 0)
  .. controls +(0, .2) and (0, .25) .. (0, 0);

  \path (0, 0) node[above right] {$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Daniel. I really appreciated your help. Just a question, which is the meaning of plus sign after thr controls commands?

Comment: My pleasure.  As for +(a,b), it represents a relative coordinate with respect to the previous point; if the previous point is (x,y), then its significance is (x,y)+(a,b).  In fact, I should have written ++(a,b), but in this case, it makes no difference.

Comment: Ok, now everything is clear!